# "reducing" a vector to a single value

Tags: functions, vectors

In programming languages like JavaScript, you can reduce an array to a single value by having a function that takes an accumulator and the current value of the array. Does such a thing exist in maths for vectors?

e.g. if I wanted to subtract each element of the vector $(4, 3, 2)$ from the previous result, the "reducer" function would be $f(a, b) = a - b$, then it would be $4 - 3 = 1$ and then $1 - 2 = -1$ (as $1$ is the result of the previous function).

Comment: Not really. Vectors are restricted to the vector space axioms in mathematics. In computer science they play the role of iterables more than mathematical vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to what Wikipedia names
[fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).
It gives this example:

> The folding of the list $[1,2,3,4,5]$ with the addition operator
> would result in $15$, the sum of the elements of the list
> $[1,2,3,4,5]$. To a rough approximation, one can think of this fold
> as replacing the commas in the list with the $+$ operation, giving
> $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$.

Many Computer Algebra Systems (CAS) implement this kind of operation.
Many use the name "fold" for the operation. Despite this, it seems
that mathematicians do not find a great need for this operation in
such generality. In very special cases, such as for addition and
multiplication, there is special notation such as $\sum_i x_i$
and $\prod_i x_i$. That is about it.

**NOTE:** There is a big difference between a list $[1,2,3]$
and a vector in a vector space. A vector has coordinates
only with respect to an ordered basis. Different basis gives
different coordinates.